# How to fix image content fixed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have fecthed data from restful api, and populated data on the tableview as follows.

Each image on the tableview has background image with white color, even though imageview constraints are defined top and bottom of the cell, but actual image(content) is not same with others.

For example, if you check first and third image are same, but the second image is bigger.

In order to give you better idea:

Image 1:
https://mobile-tha-server.appspot.com/images/image1.jpeg

Image 2:
https://mobile-tha-server.appspot.com/images/image2.jpeg

I wonder how to handle this issue.

[image]

Comment: Ensure that your image view's content mode is set to `.aspectFit`

Comment: @Paulw11, yes I set `.aspectFit`. Please check image urls that I have added.

Comment: check once are you enabled the cliptoBounds  = true for your image property

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, cliptobounds is true.

Comment: then resize your image and apply

Comment: how do I know which image to resize?

Comment: @Anbu.karthik in this case his imageView will just cut some part of needed image. Or he should know the size of the biggest image

Answer (score 0):

your constraints are defined top and bottom of the cell as you said. If you wanna your imageViews' size will be the same you should add width and height constraints to image view

Comment: image size are same, but white color background differs. Please check imageurls are provided.

Comment: well, the issue doesn't have simple solution. The imagView can not divide images on white part and the part you wanna see. It is backend problems. If you really wanna do this you should write a function that can cut your image white background

Comment: That is what I have been thinking. I am supposed to use opencv library to read raw images and remove white background.

Answer (score 0):

Set content mode of every imageView in table cell `Scale to fill`

[image]